# How do I lock my C++ function based on a parameter such that other threads calling with that same parameter cannot access it

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am building a C++ Limit Order Book, with a very high focus on speed of execution, and would like to optimise my order matching function such that it can be accessed by multiple threads as efficiently as possible.

When looking at the function `_match_orders` I have defined, I would like to ensure that no two threads can modify the same input `LimitLevel` object at the same time.

e.g. If the following call is being run on a thread `_match_orders(&order, &limit_level_price_3)`, then `_match_orders(&other_order, &limit_level_price_3)` on another thread should block until the first has been completed.

However if instead of `_match_orders(&other_order, &limit_level_price_3)`, we run `_match_orders(&other_order, &limit_level_price_4)`, I would like both to be able to run concurrently.

```cpp
class LimitOrderBook final {
    private:
        std::map<int, LimitLevel*> bids;
        std::map<int, LimitLevel*> asks;
        std::unordered_map<int, Order*> orders;
        std::mutex mtx;
        int order_id = 0;
    
    // Function inside a larger class

        void _match_orders(Order *order, LimitLevel *best_value) {
            if (best_value == nullptr) {
                return;
            }

            Order* head_order = nullptr;

            /* 
            Locking this function is necessary for calls in which the LimitLevels are the same
            but I would like calls with different LimitLevel objects to be able to still be run concurrently
            As they are modifying different objects
            */
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

            while (best_value->quantity > 0 && order->quantity > 0 && best_value->get_length() > 0) {
                // The value of the head of the LimitLevel's linked list
                int head_order_id = best_value->get_head();

                if (orders.count(head_order_id)) {
                    head_order = orders.at(head_order_id);
                } else {
                    // Already manages the deletion of loose pointers
                    best_value->pop_left();
                    continue;
                }

                // Modifies order object from input and order object from head of limit level
                if (order->quantity <= head_order->quantity) {
                    head_order->quantity -= order->quantity;
                    best_value->quantity -= order->quantity;
                    order->quantity = 0;
                } else {
                    order->quantity -= head_order->quantity;
                    best_value->quantity -= head_order->quantity;
                    head_order->quantity = 0;
                }

                if (order->quantity == 0 && orders.count(order->id)) {
                    cancel(order->id);
                }
                
                if (head_order->quantity == 0 && orders.count(head_order_id)) {
                    _pop_limit(best_value);
                    orders.erase(head_order_id);
                }
                
                // Needs its own lock regardless as modifying a larger structure
                if (best_value->quantity == 0) {
                    std::map<int, LimitLevel*> *order_tree = _get_side(!(order->is_bid));
                    if (order_tree->count(best_value->price)) {
                        order_tree->erase(best_value->price);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am using the following Order struct and LimitLevel class for this function

```cpp
struct Order final {
    const bool is_bid;
    int quantity;
    const int price;
    const int id;
    Order (const bool _is_bid, int _quantity, const int _price, const int _id) : is_bid(_is_bid), quantity(_quantity), price(_price), id(_id) {}
};

class LimitLevel final {
    public:
        const int price;
        std::queue<int> *orders;
        int quantity;

        LimitLevel(Order *order) : price(order->price), quantity(order->quantity) {
            orders = new std::queue<int>();
            orders->push(order->id);
        }

        ~LimitLevel() {
            delete orders;
        }

        inline void append(Order *order) {
            orders->push(order->id);
        }

        inline void append(int _id) {
            orders->push(_id);
        }

        inline int pop_left() {
            int val = orders->front();
            orders->pop();
            return val;
        }

        inline int get_head() {
            if (get_length()) {
                return orders->front();
            } else {
                throw std::length_error("Head attempted to be accessed from LimitLevel of length 0");
            }
        }

        inline int get_tail() {
            if (get_length()) {
                return orders->back();
            } else {
                throw std::length_error("Tail attempted to be accessed from LimitLevel of length 0");
            }
        }

        inline int get_length() {
            return orders->size();
        }
};
```

I have thought that maybe having an `unordered_set` containing the currently in-use prices would work but it seems pretty slow to constantly query, write to and delete from a set with a `condition_variable` to check if the function should block. Since there are `INT_MAX` possible prices that a LimitLevel object can contain and as such that many possible objects can exist at once. I do not want to simply make a mutex for every price level, as storing 2 billion mutexes sounds like a very inefficient approach.

Are there any simpler / faster approaches to this problem? I am not a very experienced C++ programmer (with my background mostly in Python) so any tips at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you add your mutex inside `LimitLevel`?

Comment: @Jarod42 that seems like an interesting approach that I had not thought of, will give it a try!

Comment: BTW, `LimitLevel` doesn't respect rule of 5/3/0, have unneeded indirection with pointer, has missing `const`...

Comment: @Jarod42 After posting I fixed the wierd indirection stuff with LimitLevel, dont know what I was thinking when I made it haha. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Don't start your identifiers with underline character; it's reserved for platform library internals.

Comment: as Jarod pointed out you have hidden bugs due to violating **rule 0/3/5**. The root cause is using raw pointers makes choosing rule 3 essential. If instead you keep `orders` by value, then you can use the simpler rule 0.

Comment: Learn value categories and how to use references. Since you are new to C++, using pointers is strictly banned for you; you'll shoot your feet to death.